# How to prepare a CAML query using label|guid format

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I'm getting the managed meta data from the current web context and I obtain a string like:

```
General|c32ee37d-f830-46eb-aec8-bc4e4f069c99 //label|guid
```

I would like to use that value in my CAML query. If I just search for "General", I get results but I have the web pages set up in folders, so there might be more than 1 "General" meta tag and I only want the one specific to the current page. I need to search for both the label and the guid, otherwise I would have already used split on "|" and be done with it.

In essence I'm looking for some way to make the following possible somehow:

```
label="General|c32ee37d-f830-46eb-aec8-bc4e4f069c99";

string cml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MetaData' /><Value Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>" + label+ "</Value></Eq></Where>";
```